# error NG8002: Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'. in MatDialog Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-material

*After:*

Date: 2020-03-27T14:07:28.332Z - Hash: 1e8f94aad69b7bd33179
5 unchanged chunks
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 205 kB [initial] [rendered]
Time: 1532ms
: Compiled successfully.

Failed to compile.

src/app/components/dialog.html:76:20 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'.

**dialog.component.html**

```
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> id</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**dialog.component.ts**

```
  constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<VariantsDialog>, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {}

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name'];
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavBarComponent, ErrorComponent } from './layouts';
import { SharedCommonModule } from './shared/shared-common.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { DialogComponent } from './components/dialog/dialog.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {A11yModule} from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import {ClipboardModule} from '@angular/cdk/clipboard';
import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import {PortalModule} from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import {ScrollingModule} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import {CdkStepperModule} from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {CdkTreeModule} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatBadgeModule} from '@angular/material/badge';
import {MatBottomSheetModule} from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material/chips';
import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {MatDividerModule} from '@angular/material/divider';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import {MatNativeDateModule, MatRippleModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {MatTreeModule} from '@angular/material/tree';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavBarComponent,
    ErrorComponent,
    DialogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SharedCommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    A11yModule,
    ClipboardModule,
    CdkStepperModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    PortalModule,
    ScrollingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: show your `module`'s code please

Comment: You're probably not importing the matTableModule.

Comment: matTableModule is imported in app.module.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **app.module.ts**, add in @NgModule - **entryComponents: [DialogComponent]**

```
@NgModule({
...

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [DialogComponent]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with **MODULES**, and your ***COMPONENT*** is inside that module, you'll need to import:

```
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table'
```

inside that MODULE and **not** in the APP.MODULE.TS. Like so:

(yourmodule.module.ts)

```
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatTableModule <==
  ],
```